# kinetic drag text

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

With Kinetic, is it possible to set a mouseover on a text? The code below does not work. If a replace the Text by a Rectangle, it works fine.

```
...
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var test = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    text: "test",
    textFill:"black"
});

test.on("mouseover", function(){
    alert("mouseover");
});

layer.add(test);
```

Thank you for your help!

### UPDATE:

Ok, I searched a little bit more and it seems that it is necessary to use pixel detection.

[see this tutorial fore more details](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/)

The result is not perfect for the moment but it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I have trouble dealing with a similar text behaviour and after diving in repository history I found that now Text has detectionType setted to 'pixel' by default.

Try to change your Text declaration like following :

```
var test = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    text: "test",
    textFill: 'black',
    detectionType: 'path',
    draggable: true         
});
```